# Value needs to be returned after ajax response is done

Tags: javascript, ajax

I did ajax call and got response in callback function like below:

```
var v="";
....
jq.post(contextPath + "/dmp/workspace/inlineCssExtraction", {
        jsonForSaveInlineCss: JSON.stringify(styleArr)
    }, function(data) {
v=data;
});

return v;
```

Problem I am facing is, I am getting empty value of v.
I think reason is, ajax response is taken long time and before this retun v; line is executed. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Regards

Comment: did you search first, i guess there are LOTs of similar quetions/answers there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it this way .... AJAX is asynchronous - the return expression will get executed before the callback function

```
jq.post(contextPath + "/dmp/workspace/inlineCssExtraction", {
        jsonForSaveInlineCss: JSON.stringify(styleArr)
    }, function(data) {
       processdata(data);
});
```

You could pass the data to a function which would be called on AJAX success

Comment: yeah! i forgot its an asynchronous. i will do it another way. anyways, thanks for your post!

Answer (score 0):

try this.. u may not be able to return the value with a $.post method

```
function returnText()
{
    var json = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "test.php?teststr=i", async: false}).responseText;     
    return json;
}
```

U may check [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you wanna use post method

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});
```